# Заливка ячейки в таблице MS-Wrod по условию

Tags: java, ms-word

Формируется документ Ms-Word формата .docx. В документе есть таблица, которая заполняется данными с приложения. Фон одной из ячеек нужно поменять в зависимости от значения. Как это сделать?

Comment: С помощью какой библиотеки формируете файл MSWord? И приложите  кусок кода к вопросу.

Comment: Библиотека написана в рамках проекта - поэтому кусок кода не могу приложить. Меня в большей степени интересует. Можно ли поставить условие на цвет ячейки с помощью средств MS Word.

Comment: Условного форматирования ячеек в Word нет, он не предназначен для гибкой работы с таблицами, задать цвет ячейки можно. Условие можно отработать в java и закрасить ячеку средствами вашей библиотеки. Второй вариант это Excel, там есть условное форматирование, а потом эту таблицу внедрить как объект в файл Word, но это тот еще наворот.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос. Какими способами можно еще закрасить ячейку в таблице файла MS-Word? 
Кроме выбора ячейки и ее заливки руками.